# Formatting Memoir's \sourceatright font and size

Tags: memoir, fontsize

I have been trying to get the author of a quote to show in a different font size and font style than the rest of the quotation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir} % draft

\renewcommand*{\sourceatright}[2][2em]{{%
  \unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip#1\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\tiny\sffamily{#2}
  \parfillskip\z@\finalhyphendemerits=0\par}}

\begin{document}
\begin{quotation}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ante sapien, feugiat sed elit id, tempus dictum erat. Maecenas bibendum eget lectus eu mollis.\sourceatright{Lipsum 2016}
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

From what I can tell it doesn't like the placing of `\tiny\sffamily` but I just can't work out how to do it.

The error I get is this:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
 \\sourceatright ...\sffamily {#2} \parfillskip \z
                                                  @\finalhyphendemerits =0\p...
 l.11 ...ctus eu mollis.\sourceatright{Lipsum 2016}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351). But also another adjustment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir} % draft

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sourceatright}[2][2em]{{%
  \unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip#1\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil{\tiny\sffamily#2}%
  \parfillskip\z@\finalhyphendemerits=\z@\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aliquam ante sapien, feugiat sed elit id, tempus dictum erat.
Maecenas bibendum eget lectus eu mollis.\sourceatright{Lipsum 2016}
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

The difference is that `\tiny\sffamily{#2}` should be `{\tiny\sffamily#2}`, otherwise `\tiny` would be in force when the paragraph is split into lines, with nefarious consequences.

[image]

Shorter code with `xpatch`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir} % draft

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\sourceatright}{#2}{\tiny\sffamily#2}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aliquam ante sapien, feugiat sed elit id, tempus dictum erat.
Maecenas bibendum eget lectus eu mollis.\sourceatright{Lipsum 2016}
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```